# (DECIMAL)Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the specified type

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

Everything runs fine, just error in the OLE DB destination, Error said its conversion failed and i also try to convert the ProjectedROI but convert failed. so i check the source sqlcommand the output is correct

[image: (Source sqlCommand and output)]

then i try to see check the output or the data passing thro the source and i see that the format of the output is not same with the destination column ProjectedROI which is decimal(2,2)

[image: (Pass thro output data)]

*below are error messages:*

> [Insert New Record to Fact_Sales [162]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E21.
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E21  Description: "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.".
>
> [Insert New Record to Fact_Sales [162]] Error: There was an error with Insert New Record to Fact_Sales.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input].Columns[ProjectedROI] on Insert New Record to Fact_Sales.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]. The column status returned was: "Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the specified type.".
>
> [Insert New Record to Fact_Sales [162]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Insert New Record to Fact_Sales.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907A occurred, and the error row disposition on "Insert New Record to Fact_Sales.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Insert New Record to Fact_Sales" (162) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "OLE DB Destination Input" (175). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of steps between your source and destination and you haven't shown what the data looks like after each one.  At some point, your data is going from Decimal(2,2) to something like Decimal(14,11) if I am counting right.

Starting with the source and going to each step after until you find the culprit, right click on each component and open advanced properties, and look at the datatype of the output column ProjectedROI.   Verify it has the correct Precision and Scale.